# Selenium Webdriver for Chrome Crashing vb.net

Tags: vb.net, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a program that has been working for quite a while.  Not sure what happened, but all of the sudden it crashes.  It looks like it is trying to access something on the page when this happens.  It launches Chrome, gets to a login page, but then it crashes when trying to grab the login.  Happens with multiple sites, so it isn't a site change or anything like that.

I tried converting to Firefox and InternetExplorer.  However, because Chrome lets you download a file without prompting, that is what I know will work.  I tried with FF creating a Profile and with IE creating a registry setting (to allow auto-download).  Neither worked :(

I want to go back to Chrome, but not sure what is wrong.  I even uninstalled Chrome entirely and re-installed it. Nothing :(  I tried setting ChromeDriver.exe to "Run as Administrator" - nothing crashed, but also nothing ran.

I'm at a loss :(

Comment: Show us your code trial & Configuration details.

Answer (score 0):

the latest version of chrome has a rendering bug which is causing errors when working with selenium, you can try installing the latest chromedriver but it might be better to try to find a work around with firefox for now

Comment: I did try installing version 29, it gave me the "you are using an unsupported command-line flag: --ignore-certificate-errors. Stability and security will suffer.".  Then it crashed.  I tried for quite a while to get Firefox to work.  No matter what profile I gave it, it still would not let me download the file without a prompt :(

Comment: Yeah I’m in a similar boat, I ‘m going to automate the pop ups you get to proceed past untrusted certs. This is probably a good excuse to get scripts working with more than one browser , this is not going to be the last time a browser update will break a script

Comment: Probably a good idea.  I now have mine set to use IE, Firefox,and Chrome. Still can't get around those damn "save as" popups.  Frustrating.